# Поиск и замена preg_replace php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть текст:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в третей строке стоит просто 3. то есть пустая строка.
Как удалить эту строку с помощью preg_replace?
Делаю так:

```
$row = preg_replace(array("/^(\n\d*)\.\s/"), "", $row);
```

В регулярках совсем бум-бум, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: от куда текст то берёться?

Comment: @Naumov из базы) Это просто тест)))

Comment: Ну так логичнее использовать в запросе `where text <> ''`  и не вытаскивать пустые строки во все...

Comment: @Naumov как раз это всё из одного поля, а не по отдельности, я же не настолько то глупый)

Comment: А ну тогда стоит разобрать всё и переделать таблицу

Comment: Отбой короче, не будем делать смешно)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/(^|\n)\d+\.\s*(?=\n|$)/s',"",$str);
```

Расшифровка:

```
/
(^|\n)    Начало строки или перевод каретки
\d+\.     Цифры и точка
\s*       Возможно пробельные символы (0 и более)
(?=\n|$)  За которыми идет перевод каретки или конец строки (не захватывать)
/s        Многострочная "строка". ^ и $ начало и конец всех данных
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, я бы точно не подумал, что для моего примера нужен такой большой код.

Comment: Да, приходится. короче не придумал. Это из за того что у нас текст именно многострочный и ^ работать нормально не может

Comment: Ещё раз благодарю за подробную расшифровку, класс.